# Javascript datetime format varying on different systems

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have a method to covert date to IST which is,

```
function GetCurrentIST() {
    var dte = new Date();
    dte.setTime(dte.getTime() + (dte.getTimezoneOffset() + parseInt(UtcOffset)) * 60 * 1000);

    return dte.toLocaleString();
}
```

another function calls it like this,

```
function GetStartDate(Selected) {
    var StartDt = new Date(GetCurrentIST());
    StartDt.setDate(StartDt.getDate() + parseInt(Selected));
    StartDt.setHours(0);
    StartDt.setMinutes(0);
    StartDt.setSeconds(0);
    return StartDt;
}
```

The problem I'm facing is on my machine GetCurrentIST() returns date properly.
Eg. **"10/12/2014, 12:26:37 PM"**

and the StartDt I get as :  **Dec 10 2014 12:37:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

But on my friends machine GetCurrentIST() returns date as : **"10/12/2014 12:28:40"**

and StartDt as : **Sun Oct 12 2014 12:29:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Is this problem related to datetime format or something.
does anyone have any simple solution for this problem?

Comment: can you add what is the value of the parameter `Selected` holds?

Comment: I am wondering how did you get this `the StartDt I get as : Dec 10 2014 12:37:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.. since have set the `StartDt` time to zero.

Comment: please supply what you are using to get `UtcOffset`

Comment: Utcoffset is 330 and Selected is 0,1,2... for today,tomorrow etc.
for now take Selected as 0